# Redirect to HTTPS only works the first time on Nginx

Tags: redirects, nginx

I'm currently trying to setup redirection from HTTP to HTTPS in Nginx.

Used ports:

- HTTP: 8085
- HTTPS: 443

When I access the site via `http://example.de:8085` initially, I am correctly forwarded to `https://example.de`.
On all following attempts however, the redirect leads to `https://example.de:8085` which will then give me the errorcode `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` in Firefox.

Nginx config for port 8085:

```
server { ## HTTPS redirect server

  listen *:8085;
 
  server_name example.de;
  server_tokens off;

  location / {
    return 301 https://example.de:443$request_uri;
  } 

  # Pass headers because we are serving monitoring endpoints directly without
  # redirection
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host_with_default;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 

  access_log  /var/log/server/access.log access;
  error_log   /var/log/server/error.log error;
} ## end HTTPS redirect server
```

When deleting all browser cache, it works again for only one attempt.
Therefore my best guess is currently that this might be a caching issue.
Is there anything I need to add to the response header?

Comment: Why are you using port 8085 rather than port 80?

Comment: Are you using HSTS (strict transport security)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller HSTS - that's the problem! Thanks so much for your help!

It's a legacy system that ran for years on the LAN with http on port 8085. Now we enabled https but still need all the old links to keep working. That's why the redirection has to work.

I guess the solution then is to just disable HSTS. Is it even possible to have it working with HSTS in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSTS [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) states:

> if the URI contains an explicit port component that is not
> equal to "80", the port component value MUST be preserved;

So HSTS will just change `http://example.de:8085` to `https://example.de:8085`. It never adds or removes port numbers.

One option is to disable HSTS.

The other option is to serve both HTTP and HTTPS on port 8085. You might want to have the HTTPS server on port 8085 just redirect to remove the port number. Evidentially, [this can be accomplished with some status 497 trickery using the Nginx web server](https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/).